# Is it possible to automatically simplify geometry in blender without losing object shape?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

3ds max has a sort of modifier that allows you to take a heavily subdivided mesh and take away some of the polygons that would anyhow create a single polygon (i.e they are facing the same way).

Comment: You will need to edit it again with the most refinement polygons? You want to take it away permanently or only temporally?

Comment: You can use decimate modifier or remesh (you can find this in modifiers tab)

Answer (score 33):

You could use the *Decimate Modifier*. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html). 
Please note that you only see its effect while in *object mode*.

[image]

[image]

You can find a 2 minute tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq-6X3pzUOE).

Comment: Is there a way to execute this modifier from command line and export the result?

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2876/599

Comment: The doc link in your answer is dead.

Comment: The op specifically asked for "without losing object shape", which decimate does not do as it's a lossy operation.