# Can modifiers be computed and applied from the command line?

Tags: scripting, modifiers, command-line

For heavy modifiers, the time it  takes to compute can range between a few seconds to half an hour or longer.

**Can modifiers be added, computed, and applied from the command line with some sort of indicator of progress?**

Running from the command line would be useful for running blender GUI-less without a WM to save memory.
It would also be ideal to have some idea of how far along the modifier is.

Comment: From you question its not clear if you want to create and apply the modifiers from the command-line, or just apply existing modifiers. If the modifier takses half an hour to compute I would guess you didnt set this up from the UI.

Comment: In my particular case I can set it up from the UI, as it only takes that much computation time with high settings (so I can disable visibility before setting it) But if it's possible, it would be good to add the modifier from the command line as well.

Comment: could you update your question then? For a good answer these details are important.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use [`bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_68_2/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply), e.g.

```
import bpy

for obj in bpy.context.scene.objects:
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    count = 1
    length = len(obj.modifiers)
    while obj.modifiers:
        name = obj.modifiers[0].name
        print("%s: Applying %s (%d/%d)" % (obj, name, count, length))
        bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=name)
        count += 1
print("All done.")
```

*For info on how to to run the above, [see here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1365/290).*

Comment: Thanks. This works pretty well, but I was thinking of and indicator of progress per modifier. As mentioned by ideasman42, It seems this is not possible at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply modifiers from the command line using a script, but there is no progress for each modifier.

Note that modifiers that take half an hour is not the kind of work-flow Blender is optimized for. If you are processing very high polygon meshes you may want to consider some tool like [MeshLab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/) to get them into a more usable detail level for blender to work with.